# attr() on radio return: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have this code

```
$.each($('input:checked', '#components-holder'), function(index, input){
    console.log(input.attr('value'));
});
```

And I got this error:

```
undefined is not a function
```

How can I iterate on all radio in my page and got value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object sent to your callback as `input` is *not* a jQuery object, so you can't use jQuery methods. You need to convert it into a jQuery object to use jQuery methods:

```
console.log($(input).attr('value'));
```

Or use a native DOM property:

```
console.log(input.value);
```

Or, you may wish to use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map) to get the appropriate values:

```
var values = $('#components-holder input:checked').map(function(index, input) {
    return input.value;
}).get();
```

`values` is now an array containing all the relevant values.

Comment: It works, but when I can use input.data('price') instead of input.value it doesn't work

Comment: @PawełBrzoski Again, it is a DOM object, not a jQuery object. `data` is a jQuery method, so you need a jQuery object. `$(input).data('price')` will work.